# functionals tests with behat, mink and symfony2

Tags: symfony, behat, mink

I'm trying to test the bundles Behat and Mink, but I have a problem

- I well installed the bundles
- I have launched: php app / console test-e = Behat - init @ AcmeDemoBundle, the folder Features was created
- I wrote a scenario in essai.feature
- I have launched: php app / console test-e @ Behat AcmeDemoBundle, I have got this result

> Feature: Test
>              In order to test
>              As a developer
>              I Need To Be Able to submit a contact form
>
> Scenario: Navigate to the welcome page # src \ Acme \ DemoBundle \ Features \       >essai.feature: 6
>          Given I am on "/ crud / Article"
>
> Scenario 1 (1 undefined)
>     1 step (1 undefined)
>     0m0.243s
>
> You Can Implement step definitions for undefined steps with snippets thesis:
>
> / **
>          * @ Given / ^ I am on "([^"] *) "$ /
>          * /
>           public function iAmOn ($ argument1)
>          {
>              throw new PendingException ();
>          }

- When I tried to implement the definitions, I have launched
  php app / console test-e @ Behat AcmeDemoBundle -dl

But, I get nothing at all! nothing is executed and the file FeatureContext is not modified

Please help me to find a solution

Comment: Could you fix code formatting, please? Also, what does it mean that you get nothing? What did you expect to get?

Comment: thank you and sorry for the format of the code, I fixed the problem

Comment: You could still clean up your question and share the answer for future generations...

Comment: in fact, I just copy the method "function iAmOn" generated in the console under the file FeatureContext.php

thank's a lot

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not told Behat where to look for your main context file. You need to either explicitly load FeatureContext.php in your behat configuration file:

```
# config/behat.yml
default:
autoload: [ %paths.base%/../features/bootstrap ]
suites:
  default:
      paths: [ %paths.base%/../features ]
      filters:
      contexts:
          - FeatureContext
```

Or place FeatureContext.php exactly where Behat searches for it by default. From the ["context class requirements"](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/4.contexts.html) section of the Behat docs:

> The context class should be discoverable and loadable by Behat. That
>   means you should somehow tell Behat about your class file. Behat comes
>   with a PSR-0 autoloader out of the box and the default autoloading
>   directory is features/bootstrap. That’s why the default FeatureContext
>   is loaded so easily by Behat. You can place your own classes under
>   features/bootstrap by following the PSR-0 convention or you can even
>   define your own custom autoloading folder via behat.yml.

Answer (score 0):

If a step definition has any errors it can cause one of those "nothing happens" scenarios. It's aways best to copy the new step def from the console output and paste it in the your FeatureContext before you begin implementing it.